# How does tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: works exactly and how to customize this view dynamically

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm setting a header for a `UITableView`'s sections and everything works perfectly :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let headerView = MyCustomHeaderView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    return headerView
}
```

The header of every section is blue, as I expect it to be.

Now, I'd like to change this color when my `UITableView` is scrolling so I implemented this method in a `UITableView` extension :

```
extension UITableView
{
    func setHeadersColor(color: UIColor)
    {
        guard let delegate = self.delegate
            else {return}
        guard delegate.respondsToSelector(#selector(UITableViewDelegate.tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)))
            else {return}

        for i in 0...self.numberOfSections
        {
            if let header = delegate.tableView!(self, viewForHeaderInSection: i) as? MyCustomHeaderView
            {
                header.backgroundColor = color
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call this method, `header.backgroundColor = color` gets called but the background color of the header doesn't change.

So my questions are :

- is the instance of `UIView` returned by `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` the same as the actual `UIView` displayed on the header ? Is it a copy ? Is it something else ?
- how could I change this header view dynamically ? Do I have to call `reloadData` just to change my header's background color ? That would be a waste of resources..

Comment: You can get the view that's in the table with `tableView.headerViewForSection(x)`

Comment: I tried as well, but I got the same results

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is related to not reuse of view, so your view constantly is created here

```
let headerView = MyCustomHeaderView()
```

and returned, always with blue background color

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks Reinier, but there's no reusability mechanism for header views unfortunately (  http://stackoverflow.com/a/960157/3844377 )

Comment: Yes but then how you can do this?, If I found some decent way I will post my results

Comment: Alright thanks, for now I'm using `reloadData`, it doesn't impact the performances of my app but I just don'te really like to do unnecessary stuff :)